# C# VS2008 remove message box from dll?

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem in project i have dll, when i use function "open" show message box with advertisement where i need push "no thanks" how i can remove this message or simulate push on this button ?
 is MatriX XMPP SDK http://www.ag-software.de it cost too much for me (((

Comment: Which dll is it? You can probably overcome that by paying a license fee to the creators of the dll.

Comment: It not Commercial application the dll is  "Matrix.dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um.. not sure why you want to play with that. It may be dangerous malware/adware.

see http://www.fbmsoftware.com/spyware-net/process/matrix_dll/820/ and check the file size/hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can normally get around these by paying for a licence for the software you're using.

Comment: It dll need only in one project personal using.

Comment: @Alexandr You'd still have to licence it, to stay within the law

Comment: Everything is negotiable.  Contact the owner(s) of the DLL and make a compelling case why you should get a no-strings-attached license to their product.  It is unlikely those owners post to Stackoverflow, you have to pick up the phone.